# OpenShift Empty WordPress Repo

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I signed up for OpenShift and created a new WordPress application. Went through the typical WP setup screens in the browser, and now have a fresh instance of WP. I need to start hacking away at WP, so I

```
git clone ssh://<my-app-repo-url> /path-to-my-project
```

in my shell, but the

```
/path-to-my-project/php
```

folder is empty!

I ssh'd into my application and the

```
/var/lib/openshift/<uid>/app-root/repo/php
```

folder contains all the WP source. Why is the clone operation not pulling down these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install WordPress using the quickstart, it downloads WordPress and installs it on your gear, not using git.  Refer to the directions here (https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example) in the readme for more information.

Comment: So, I voted this up, because I took your word that following the directions there would work. I have finally gotten around to following them, but they did not work! I created a new WP app from the command line, but I still have the exact same issue: When I clone the repo, there are no source files!